# How does this oscillator work?

Tags: rf, oscillator, radio, ham-radio

I am trying to understand the following oscillator from a Cyclone 40 transceiver (http://www.4sqrp.com/cyclone.php).

Here the the VFO (in the actual device, the inductor has a bolt through it to tune the oscillator):

[image: VFO of Cyclone 40]

In my simulation, the voltage at the gate rises until around 1.6V, which I assume is the threshold voltage of the device.  At that point, a small amount of current starts going into the drain.

Can someone help me understand how this oscillator works?

Also, is the transistor in its triode region the entire time (in steady state)?  I think it is, as Vgs < Vds - Vth.  If I zoom in at the bottom of the Id current curve, it does a funny upwards hop before going down again - what is that?

[image]

Comment: Why not include an image of the "funny upwards hop"?

Comment: Because I'm new at stackexchange and it would only let me include a single image at my current reputation level.  :)

Comment: Give us a link to the image and we can edit it into your question.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to get oscillators to start in simulations... you can "kick 'em" sometimes... adding a voltage pulse somewhere at the beginning.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I have it graphed here: http://imgur.com/KqrvcHX  I have the current into the FET graphed and at the bottom it goes back up a bit and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold - Yeah, that hung me up for a bit until I found the 'startup' directive I used there to start the voltage source at zero.

Comment: You should look for the setting that increases the number of samples, there may be something hiding from the graph due to low'ish sample rate.

Comment: @jippie is right, your time step is too big. That upwards hop is only two data points.

Comment: Here is the hop zoomed in with smaller timesteps: http://imgur.com/dOTe5rt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FET is used as a common source amplifier.  It will amplify voltage from its gate to its drain.  It can amplify well over unity, but the polarity is negative, which would normally prevent it from oscillating.

The trick in this case is the capacitors and the inductor phase shift the signal enough at the right frequency so that you end up with positive gain from gate to drain.  Adjusting the inductance tunes this frequency.

Comment: There is no supply of power to the drain so how can this happen Olin?

Comment: @Andy: It's getting power thru R1 and L1.  The average drain voltage will stabilize at the gate voltage that allows the drain current to match what is coming thru R1.

Comment: +1 for that - I believe you!!. Might try a sim on this tomorrow.

Comment: So, as the voltage reaches the threshhold, I see it leveling off  and then start oscillating, as seen here: http://imgur.com/W3Lcghm   But why does it start oscillating at that point?

Comment: @Ben due to feedback through the LC network. The feedback signal pushes down the gate voltage, making the transistor stop conducting. Then because there is already a tiny amount of charge swinging in from L to C in the network, half a period later the transistor's gate gets a little kick up causing an amplified signal to pull the drain down. Which in turn adds to the charge in the LC circuit, which swings with a slightly larger amplitude ... pushes the gate below its threshold and half a cycle later pulls it up, causing an even larger drain current to be fed into the LC ... etc.

Comment: @jippie - The thing I don't understand in your explanation is that when I graph the current through each of the pins of the transistor, they always have current going through them - http://imgur.com/AHxATRN  Also, this shows gate current where I was expecting hardly any.  Am I being mislead by the simulation?

Comment: @Ben: The gate has capacitance, so there will be gate current when the gate voltage changes.